# how to implement an applyif for Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I'd like to have an `applyif` to work like:

```
builder.applyif(<condition expression>) {
    builder.set...
}
```

to be equal with:

```
builder.apply {
    if (<condition expression>) {
        builder.set...
    }
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: I encourage to learn the language enough so you can construct this yourself. Read about [extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) and [higher-order functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html). The first parameter could be plain boolean. The second is your lambda.

Comment: even though I am too late for it: what did you even try to solve it? Rather follow @EugenPechanec's advice then just copying the solution.

Comment: Personally i'd stick with the standard library: `builder.takeIf { condition_code }?.apply { applied_code }` Any new reader of your code will be familiar with those and won't have to study and memorize your hand-rolled extension funs.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, notice that the expression `builder.takeIf { condition_code }?.apply { applied_code }` returns null if the condition is false, whereas the `applyif` that is asked for returns a builder object whether the condition is true or false, which is what you'd want when chaining calls on a builder IMO.

Comment: @MichalBorowiecki My take was that you already have the builder object in the `builder` variable, and the ability to directly chain onto the closing `}` doesn't carry enough weight vs. introducing custom API. If you don't perceive any value in sticking to the familiar idioms from the standard library, you may see it differently.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, of course. You can nearly program anything, ***but*** don't reinvent the wheel. Look at the bottom of the answer to see a standard Kotlin approach without own extension function(s) which may already suffice your needs (not exactly `applyIf` though).

Now, however, lets see how an `applyIf` might be implemented:

```
inline fun <T> T.applyIf(predicate: T.() -> Boolean, block: T.() -> Unit): T = apply { 
  if (predicate(this)) 
    block(this) 
}
```

Don't forget the `inline` if you are implementing extension functions with lambdas.

Here is an example usage of the above.

```
// sample class
class ADemo {
  fun isTrue() = true
}

// sample usage using method references
ADemo().applyIf(ADemo::isTrue, ::println)

// or if you prefer or require it, here without
ADemo().applyIf( { isTrue() } ) {
  println(this)
}
```

If you just want to supply a boolean instead, you can use the following extension function:

```
inline fun <T> T.applyIf(condition : Boolean, block : T.() -> Unit) : T = apply { 
  if(condition) block(this) 
}
```

and call it with:

```
val someCondition = true
ADemo().applyIf(someCondition) {
  println(this)
}
```

And now a possible ***Kotlin standard way*** with which more people could be familiar:

```
ADemo().takeIf(ADemo::isTrue)
       ?.apply(::println)

// or
ADemo().takeIf { it.isTrue() }
       ?.apply { println(this) }
```

If they do remember (I actually didn't until I saw Marko Topolniks comment) they should immediately know what's going on.
However, if you require the given value (i.e. `ADemo()`) after calling `takeIf` this approach might not work for you as the following will set the variable to `null` then:

```
val x = ADemo().takeIf { false }
               ?.apply { println(this) /* never called */ }
// now x = null
```

whereas the following will rather set the variable to the `ADemo`-instance:

```
val x = ADemo().applyIf(false) { println(this) /* also not called */ }
// now x contains the ADemo()-instance
```

Chaining the builder calls might not be so nice then. Still you can also accomplish this via standard Kotlin functions by combining the `takeIf` with `apply` or `also` (or `with`, `let`, `run`, depending on whether you want to return something or not or you prefer working with `it` or `this`):

```
val x = builder.apply {
  takeIf { false }
    ?.apply(::println) // not called
  takeIf { true }
    ?.apply(::println) // called
}
// x contains the builder
```

But then again we are nearly there where you were already in your question. The same definitely looks better with `applyIf`-usage:

```
val x = builder.applyIf(false, ::println) // not called
               .applyIf(true) { 
                 println(this) // called
               }
// x contains the builder
```

Comment: Please add an example of use (I'm looking for the first lambda in parentheses and the second outside). Oh, and the inline modifier is missing.

Comment: Right... Funny enough I thought about that first but must have forgotten while writing :-D adding the sample soon

Comment: added. Thanks for the hints

Comment: @Roland, this is helpful. Is there any sort of way to do a `takeIf` without executing the `T`?  In the example above,

    `ADemo().takeIf(ADemo::isTrue)`

ADemo will be created, then will be taken only if the predicate is true. Is there a way to only execute the `T` if the predicate is true?

Comment: @Nick that's probably a question for its own.. sounds like a job for a "simple" `if` or `when`..

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can, you just need an extension function so you can call it on the `builder`, and you need it to take a `Boolean` parameter and the lambda to execute.

If you look at the source of the `apply` function itself, it will help with most of the implementation:

```
public inline fun <T> T.apply(block: T.() -> Unit): T {
    block()
    return this
}
```

Based on this, `applyIf` can be as simple as:

```
inline fun <T> T.applyIf(condition: Boolean, block: T.() -> Unit): T {
    return if (condition) this.apply(block) else this
}
```

Usage looks like this:

```
builder.applyIf(x > 200) {
    setSomething()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
fun <T> T.applyIf(condition: Boolean, block: T.() -> T) = if (condition) block() else this

fun main() {
    println("a".applyIf(true) { uppercase() }) // A
    println("a".applyIf(false) { uppercase() }) // a
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With an immutable value (e.g. Compose `Modifier`) the `apply` will not work, then `this` explicitly has to be returned, something like this

```
inline fun <T> T.applyIf(predicate: T.() -> Boolean, block: T.() -> T): T =
    if (predicate())
        block(this)
    else
        this
```