# Kotlin: how to put two statements "apply" and "let" together in a nice way?

Tags: kotlin, apply, nullable, builder, let

I'll stick to abstractions in code for simplicity.
So I'm writing a function that takes some nullable color to set it only if it's not null. I'm using a Builder, the code looks something like this:

```
private fun buildIcon(color: Color? = null) =
    Icon.Builder()
        .apply{ color?.let { this.setColor(color) } }
```

It works but it looks kind of ugly, how do I make it into one statement, so something like applyIfNotNull(color) { this.setColor(it) }, but maybe simpler, I just want to merge these statements into one. I tried to do this like in [how to implement an applyif for Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51606956/how-to-implement-an-applyif-for-kotlin) but can't make it work.

Comment: It would be worth checking whether setting the colour to `null` does any harm. (For example, it might tell the icon to inherit the colour from its container.) If not, then you could omit the check and _always_ call `setColor()`.

Comment: It actually creates icon from resource and if setColor is not provided, you get the default color - that's what should happend when we don't provide color to buildIcon(). also setColor function takes non-nullable argument, so It's not the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your `applyIfNotNull` function like this:

```kotlin
inline fun <T, U> T.applyIfNotNull(value: U?, block: T.(U) -> Unit): T {
    if(value != null)
        this.block(value)
    return this
}
```

Usage:

```kotlin
private fun buildIcon(color: Color? = null) =
    Icon.Builder().applyIfNotNull(color) { this.setColor(it) }
```

You can verify it [here](https://pl.kotl.in/Bx_4G4y7f).

Comment: That's what I was looking for. The only thing I would change is to do apply = {} instead of returning this but it looks good